# Highlight keyword without case sensitive?

Tags: php

I successfully highlight keywords with using this

```
 function highlight($str, $keywords)
{

$keywords2 = $keywords;
$keywords = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', strip_tags(trim($keywords))); // filter

$str = str_replace($keywords2,"<strong>$keywords2</strong>",$str);


$var = '';

foreach(explode(' ', $keywords) as $keyword)
{
$replacement = "<strong>".$keyword."</strong>";
$var .= $replacement." ";

$str = str_ireplace(" ".$keyword." ", " ".$replacement." ", $str);
$str = str_ireplace(" ".$keyword, " ".$replacement, $str);

}

$str = str_ireplace(rtrim($var), "<strong>".$keywords."</strong>", $str);

return $str;

}
```

However, its case sensitive. How to make it work without case sensitive ?

Comment: I think you want the `i` parameter on `preg_replace`. `preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you now. It expects the keywords to be a string with spaces in between.

Obviously if this is taking user input then you will need to escape that input somehow.

```
function highlight($str, $keywords) {

    // Convert keywords to an array of lowercase keywords
    $keywords = str_replace(' ', ',', $keywords);
    $keywordsArray = explode(',', strtolower($keywords));

    // if any lowercase version of a word in the string is found in the
    // keywords array then wrap that word in <strong> tags in the string
    foreach (explode(' ', $str) as $word) {
        if (in_array(strtolower($word), $keywordsArray)) {
            $str = str_replace("$word ", "<strong>$word</strong> ", $str);
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

The space after the $word var and its replacement are to prevent double encapsulating the keyword if it appears in the string more than once.

example usage:

```
$str = 'the quick brown fox jumped over Mr Brown the lazy dog';
$keywords = 'the brown fox';
echo highlight($str, $keywords);
```

will output:

```
<strong>the</strong> quick <strong>brown</strong> <strong>fox</strong> jumped over Mr <strong>Brown</strong> <strong>the</strong> lazy dog
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Just 1 problem. It makes strtolower all the keywords that it highlighted. Anyway to avoid that ?

Comment: @user198989 I have updated the answer to preserve case of the words in the string.

Comment: You forgot to add  { right after foreach. Also, It doesnt highlight :/

Comment: @user198989 the missing { was a typo and probably what was stopping it working for you. I have tested this now and it works just fine

Comment: I use it as highlight($sentence,"make these highlight"); but it doesnt add the strong tags, just tried it now.

Comment: The keywords need to be comma separated. Use highlight($sentence, "make, these, highlight")

Comment: Thanks but I need to use it without commas. I am using it on a search results page, need to highlight what users search.

Comment: I have updated the answer again. This should work now if I understand your use-case correctly.

Comment: It works, but it makes all lowercase :/ Possible to avoid that ?

Comment: I can't see why it would effect the case of the words in the string, it certainly doesn't in my testing. Are you sure there is nothing else in your code doing that?

Comment: If there are uppercase words, it automatically makes it all lowercase. This is the problem.

Comment: uppercase words in the string or in the keywords? Yes it runs strtolower on the keywords but I thought you wanted to preserve the case of the string, not the keywords?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have got a little confused with your solution, try this instead (works for any case, may need to extend special chars available following keywords though):

```
function highlightKeywords($str, $keywords) {
    $keywordsArray = explode(' ', strip_tags(trim($keywords)));

    foreach ($keywordsArray as $keyword) {
        $str = preg_replace("/($keyword)([\s\.\,])/i", "<strong>$1</strong>$2", $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

(Assuming keywords are space delimited as in your example code)

Comment: It makes all highlighted keywords to lowercase. Anyway to avoid that ?

Comment: Sample does not put in lowercase, /i in regex will match any case and the reuse of the captured keyword will maintain case - tested